# Why multi-field mapping is not working with tire gem for elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapping, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using elastic search to enhance search capabilities in my app. Search is working perfectly, however sorting is not for fields with multiple words.

When I try to sort the search by log 'message', I was getting the error:

"Can't sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field"

I googled the error and find out that I can use multi-fields mapping on the :message field (one analyzed and the other one not) to sort them. So I did this:

```rb
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  tire.mapping do
    indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :source, type: 'string'
    indexes :level, type: 'string'
    indexes :created_at, :type => 'date', :include_in_all => false
    indexes :updated_at, :type => 'date', :include_in_all => false
    indexes :message, type: 'multi_field', fields: { 
      analyzed: {type: 'string', index: 'analyzed'},
      message: {type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed} 
    }
    indexes :domain, type: 'keyword'
  end
end
```

But, for some reason is not passing this mapping to ES.

```rb
rails console
Log.index.delete #=> true
Log.index.create #=> 200 : {"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}
Log.index.import Log.all #=> 200 : {"took":243,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"logs","_type":"log","_id":"5 ... ...

# Index mapping for :message is not the multi-field 
# as I created in the Log model... why?

Log.index.mapping
=> {"log"=>
  {"properties"=>
    {"created_at"=>{"type"=>"date", "format"=>"dateOptionalTime"},
     "id"=>{"type"=>"long"},
     "level"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "message"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "source"=>{"type"=>"string"},
     "updated_at"=>{"type"=>"date", "format"=>"dateOptionalTime"}}}}

# However if I do a Log.mapping I can see the multi-field
# how I can fix that and pass the mapping correctly to ES? 

Log.mapping
=> {:id=>{:index=>:not_analyzed, :type=>"string"},
 :source=>{:type=>"string"},
 :level=>{:type=>"string"},
 :created_at=>{:type=>"date", :include_in_all=>false},
 :updated_at=>{:type=>"date", :include_in_all=>false},
 :message=>
  {:type=>"multi_field",
   :fields=>
    {:message=>{:type=>"string", :index=>"analyzed"},
     :untouched=>{:type=>"string", :index=>:not_analyzed}}},
 :domain=>{:type=>"keyword"}}
```

So, `Log.index.mapping` is the current mapping in ES which doesn't contain the multi-field that I created. Am I missing something? and why the multi-field is shown in `Log.mapping` but not in `Log.index.mapping`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have changed the workflow from:

```
Log.index.delete; Log.index.create; Log.import
```

to

```
Log.index.delete; Log.create_elasticsearch_index; Log.import
```

The `MyModel.create_elasticsearch_index` creates the index with proper mapping from model definition. See Tire's issue [#613](https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/613).

Comment: Running these in a rails console also made it easy for me to diagnose an error that was preventing my index from being updated so thanks for that.