# ElasticSearch : Combining query string with term filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using tire and elasticsearch in my rails project, which is a retail site for car parts. ES is powering a faceted search page used for browsing the parts catalog. My question is: **How can I make the term filters return only exact matches while searching the same fields with a query string, making use of analyzers only on the query string?**

I hope that makes sense. I will try to provide an example:

The model/index in question is called Parts. Assume that a part has mappings called `categories` and `sub_categories`. If a user selects the Brake *category* and the Brake Caliper Carrier *subcategory* (creating term filters) I have to make sure that parts from the Brake Caliper *subcategory* are not also returned – it is a separate subcategory. I do, however, want the user to be able to simply enter something like "brakes" into the search field (creating a query_string) and get results from products within all of those categories.

Here is the relevant code from the Part model:

```
def to_indexed_json
    fits = fitments.try(:map) do |fit|
      {
        make: fit.try(:make).try(:name),
        make_id: fit.try(:make).try(:id),
        model: fit.try(:model).try(:name),
        model_id: fit.try(:model).try(:id),
        year: fit.year,
        sub_model: fit.sub_model
      }
    end
    {
      id: id,
      name: name,
      description: description,
      fitments: fits,
      categories: root_categories,
      sub_categories: sub_categories,
      price: price,
      condition_id: condition_id,
      country_of_origin: country_of_origin,
      brand: brand,
      oem: oem,
      thumb_url: part_images.first.try(:image).try(:thumb).try(:url),
      city: user.try(:city),
      inventory: inventory,
      part_number: part_number,
      user: user.try(:public_name)
    }.to_json
  end

  mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 40
    indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 12

    indexes :price, type: "integer"
    indexes :country_of_origin, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :condition_id, type: "integer"
    indexes :brand, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :oem, type: "boolean"
    indexes :city, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :inventory, type: "integer"
    indexes :part_number, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :user, index: :not_analyzed

    indexes :thumb_url, index: :not_analyzed

    indexes :fitments do
      indexes :make
      indexes :make_id, type: "integer" #, index: 'not_analyzed'
      indexes :model
      indexes :model_id, type: "integer" #, index: 'not_analyzed'
      indexes :year, type: "integer"
      indexes :sub_model
    end

    indexes :categories do
      indexes :name, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :id, type: "integer"
    end

    indexes :sub_categories do
      indexes :name, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :id, type: "integer"
    end

  end

def search(params={})

  query_filters = []

  tire.search(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20) do

    query_filters << { :term => { 'fitments.make_id' => params[:make] }} if params[:make].present?
    query_filters << { :term => { 'fitments.model_id' => params[:model] }} if params[:model].present?
    query_filters << { :term => { 'categories.name' => params[:category] }} if params[:category].present?
    query_filters << { :term => { 'sub_categories.name' => params[:sub_category] }} if params[:sub_category].present?
    query_filters << { :term => { 'city' => params[:city] }} if params[:city].present?
    query_filters << { :term => { 'condition_id' => params[:condition] }} if params[:condition].present?
    query_filters << { :term => { 'brand' => params[:brand] }} if params[:brand].present?
    query_filters << { :term => { 'oem' => params[:oem] }} if params[:oem].present?

    query do
      filtered do
        query {
          if params[:query].present?
            string params[:query]
          else
            all
          end
        }
        filter :and, query_filters unless query_filters.empty?
      end
    end

    facet("categories") { terms 'categories.name', size: 50 } unless params[:category].present?
    facet("cities") { terms 'city', size: 50 } unless params[:city].present?
    if params[:category].present? && !params[:sub_category].present?
      facet("sub_categories") { terms 'sub_categories.name', size: 50 }
    end
    facet("condition_id") { terms 'condition_id', size: 50 } unless params[:condition].present?
    facet("brand") { terms 'brand', size: 50 } unless params[:brand].present?
    facet("oem") { terms 'oem', size: 2 } unless params[:oem].present?

    size params[:size] if params[:size]

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`multi_field`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/) feature of Elasticsearch and filter on the non-analyzed fields; see eg. [Why multi-field mapping is not working with tire gem for elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690975/why-multi-field-mapping-is-not-working-with-tire-gem-for-elasticsearch)

Comment: Thanks karmi. Its a huge help that you are here on SO supporting your gem!